# Replacing lines in one file based of indices in a second file

Tags: awk, sed, files, osx, string

I have two files:

Ref.txt which contains:

```
ABCDEFG,15147,1,2,6
HIJKLMN,500,3,4
```

and Seq.txt which contains:

```
ABCXXXX
ABCDEXX
IIJKXXX
HIHKXXX
LMNOPQR
BBCDEXX
STUVWXY
```

I would like to replace the certain lines in the Seq.txt file. The indices of the lines that should be replaces are listed in fields 3-end of Ref.txt file, and what the lines should be replaced with is located in field 1 of the same line in the Ref.txt file. The output I am looking for in this example is this:

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
HIJKLMN
LMNOPQR
ABCDEFG
STUVWXY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
  NR==FNR {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) a[$i] = $1; next} 
  FNR in a {$0 = a[FNR]} 
  1
' Ref.txt Seq.txt 
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
HIJKLMN
LMNOPQR
ABCDEFG
STUVWXY
```